# Problem installing Ionic on Nuxt 3 application

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, nuxt.js

I've been trying to create an app with Nuxt 3 and Ionic.

When I try to install ionic with the command `npm install @nuxtjs/ionic -D`, I get this error:

```
npm WARN deprecated vm2@3.9.19: The library contains critical security issues and should not be used for production! The maintenance of the project has been discontinued. Consider migrating your code to isolated-vm.

added 174 packages, and audited 1044 packages in 25s

156 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

8 critical severity vulnerabilities

Some issues need review, and may require choosing
a different dependency.

Run `npm audit` for details.
```

Any ideas on how to fix that? It drives me crazy.

I tried to change the node version, but it didn't make any difference.

Comment: Usual NPM warnings, nothing to worry about, you can proceed.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because `@nuxtjs/ionic` is internally importing package `vm2@3.9.19` from a [discontinued project](https://github.com/patriksimek/vm2), thus potentially vulnerable to future security exploits. It is not an error, just sort of a passive agressive warning from `npm` to keep you aware that your project has a potential weakness.

From my point of view, the best thing you can do right now, is to wait for Ionic developers [as they are aware of the situation and are working on the update](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/pull/5042). Once new version comes out, just reinstall `@nuxtjs/ionic` and you should be fine.

There are ways how to play with dependencies manually via `overrides` section in `package.json`, but since this one is burried like 7 levels deep inside 3rd party package, it will probably get you into more trouble rather than solving the issue.

Comment: I see but the weird thing about it is that everyone I see on youtube that uses `@nuxtjs/ionic` it runs without any problem or vulnerabilities.

Comment: Well, `vm2` project was marked as discontinued in July. Might be not so long yet. The issue was first reported on July 25th - https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/5030